# How to import a local database file into mySQL using phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I would like to use phpMyAdmin interface to import a database, but the Import option allows you only to upload it from remote computer, while my file is already on the server. Is there any option to do that? I'm working on the Apache envoirement. Many thanks!

Comment: please give error screenshot

Comment: phpmyadmin is a tool to administer a database remotely. If the file is on the server and you have access to command line, then use that to import the file.

Comment: we can import from local computer